# Asynchronous python code vs. synchronous code with regards to generating fake profiles

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous

I have two pieces of code that generate fake profiles which I would eventually implement in a django application.
Asynchronous implementation:

```
from faker import Faker
import time
import asyncio
from pprint import pprint

generator = Faker()

async def main():
    tasks = [loop.run_in_executor(None, generator.profile) for _ in range(10000)]
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    return [t.result() for t in tasks]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    times = []
    for i in range(10):
        tic = time.time()
        r = loop.run_until_complete(main())
        times.append(time.time() - tic)
    pprint(times)
```

Synchronous implementation:

```
from timeit import timeit, repeat
import time
from pprint import pprint

setup = '''
from faker import Faker
generator = Faker()
'''
statement = '''
[generator.profile() for _ in range(10000)]
'''
pprint(repeat(setup = setup, stmt = statement, number = 1, repeat = 10))
```

Time deltas (seconds) when I ran the asynchronous program:

```
[13.820850849151611,
 14.007930278778076,
 14.795434951782227,
 15.011482238769531,
 17.231173038482666,
 15.71168303489685,
 14.603086233139038,
 16.898462295532227,
 13.315504789352417,
 19.154038906097412]
```

Time deltas when I ran the synchronous program:

```
[8.275394250002137,
 8.110358166999504,
 7.9784701250027865,
 7.897503958000016,
 8.049156667002535,
 8.064224791000015,
 8.457068499999878,
 8.627016083999479,
 8.420571250000648,
 8.65705112499927]
```

My question is why the asynchronous code is much slower? My expectation would be the opposite.
This code would eventually be implemented into a django APIView where the end user would be able to generate a specified amount of synthetic data.
Any responses would be much appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Why would you expect the asyncio version to be faster? You aren't doing any non-blocking tasks like network calls (at least AFAICT from the code you posted). You're just adding extra overhead to a basic for loop.

Comment: The golden rule : async-io is only for IO-bound tasks, while multi-threading/processing is for CPU-bound tasks. An IO-bound task is when you are waiting for inputs to be available (keypresses, reading packets from the network, ...) or outputs to be completed (writing to a file, sending packets on the network, ...). A CPU-bound task is also called "number crunching", and it makes your fan spin fast to cool it down. These are different ways to attain concurrency, with different performance characteristics. I recommend you the [Real Python tutorial](https://realpython.com/python-concurrency/).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I was under the assumption that the Faker object would be reading from a database and my aim was to try and parallelize that process.

Comment: @AmundeepSinghDhaliwal using asyncio will *probably* speed that up depending on how long the db calls take (measure!). But you aren't going to see that with a synchronous mock in a for loop. As I said before for synchronous blocking code I would expect asyncio to be *slower* because it's pure overhead in that scenario.